# How to add a field to an existing JSON in Velocity?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, velocity, templating, vtl

I have a JSON coming from a request body and I'm trying to use VTL to map it by adding an additional field to it. The request body looks like this:

```
{
   "name": "John",
   "age": 20,
   "address": {
      "street": "Albert's Street",
      "City": "Test City"
   }
}
```

In AWS, I'm trying to map this request body to have an additional field which is coming from a parameter in the URL path to become this:

```
{
   "name": "John",
   "age": 20,
   "address": {
      "street": "Albert's Street",
      "City": "Test City"
   },
   "operation": "$input.params('path.operation')"
}
```

I have tried looping through with something like this but it doesn't work very well:

```
#set($allParams = $input.path('$'))
{
#foreach($type in $allParams.keySet())
    #set($params = $allParams.get($type))
"$type" : {
    #foreach($paramName in $params.keySet())
    "$paramName" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($params.get($paramName))"
        #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
}
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
}
```

Moreover, this only works for those with 2 levels in the JSON. It doesn't work for those at the first level of the JSON or if I happen to have more than 2 levels in the JSON payload.

All I need is simply appending one more field into the existing request body of a JSON payload. How can I do that in Velocity?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `operation` property to the `input` JSON like this:

```
#set ($input.path('$').operation = 'example')
$input.json('$')
```

The above results in the following for your example:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 20,
  "address": {
    "street": "Albert's Street",
    "City": "Test City"
  },
  "operation": "example"
}
```

Of course, you can use a value from `params` instead of `'example'`.

By the way, consider running the param through `$util.escapeJavaScript` for added security.